# What the Error: The page you were looking for doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, refinery

I unload my Refinery application (ROR) on Heroku. I complete this commands: `git push heroku master` and `heroku open`. And I face to problem:  The page you were looking for doesn't exist.You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

**Heroku logs:**

```
ark@ark-Aspire-5750G:~/mirprirodi$ heroku logs
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570243+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2211813042819250636__call__2480927433245681056__callbacks'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570254+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570261+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570267+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570269+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570277+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570285+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-01T15:37:06.553873+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 94.255.67.165 at 2014-07-01 15:37:06 +0000
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569964+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569966+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569972+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"refinery_pages"'::regclass
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569975+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569980+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1163:in `exec_no_cache'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569985+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2014-07-01T15:40:02.721866+00:00 heroku[run.2189]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570007+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570014+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:229:in `yield'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570018+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:131:in `locking_enabled?'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570020+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/relation.rb:170:in `exec_queries'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570023+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570033+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570101+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570251+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570280+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570099+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570134+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570153+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570171+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570186+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570248+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570258+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570264+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570268+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570272+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570276+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570284+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569982+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:660:in `block in exec_query'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570029+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/refinerycms-pages-2.1.2/app/controllers/refinery/pages_controller.rb:74:in `find_page'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570032+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570046+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570138+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570141+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570155+0
0:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570162+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570163+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570164+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570166+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:40:09.971485+00:00 heroku[run.2189]: State changed from up to complete
2014-07-01T15:40:02.600202+00:00 heroku[run.2189]: Awaiting client
2014-07-01T15:40:02.636111+00:00 heroku[run.2189]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-07-01T15:40:09.961721+00:00 heroku[run.2189]: Process exited with status 0
2014-07-01T15:39:21.778866+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stormy-caverns-7064.herokuapp.com request_id=daa97508-63b7-4b44-ac56-f8e32fb9b38b fwd="94.255.67.165" dyno=web.1 connect=11ms service=18ms status=500 bytes=939
2014-07-01T15:38:20.220947+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 94.255.67.165 at 2014-07-01 15:38:20 +0000
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249464+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249469+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "refinery_pages" does not exist
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249471+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"refinery_pages"'::regclass
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249473+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249474+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249476+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249478+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249479+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249481+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"refinery_pages"'::regclass
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249482+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249484+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249485+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249487+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1163:in `async_exec'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249489+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1163:in `exec_no_cache'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249491+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:660:in `block in exec_query'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249493+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249495+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249496+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249497+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249499+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1292:in `column_definitions'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249500+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:855:in `columns'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249501+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249503+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:229:in `yield'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249504+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:229:in `columns'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249506+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:238:in `columns_hash'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249507+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:131:in `locking_enabled?'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249509+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/relation.rb:170:in `exec_queries'
2014-07-01T15:41:03.969437+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stormy-caverns-7064.herokuapp.com request_id=fd7f63e3-a163-46a9-ba8d-95b13ea94732 fwd="94.255.67.165" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=101ms status=404 bytes=1072
2014-07-01T15:41:03.880489+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 94.255.67.165 at 2014-07-01 15:41:03 +0000
2014-07-01T15:41:03.962488+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected
2014-07-01T15:41:03.884002+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"locale"=>:en}
2014-07-01T15:41:03.883975+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Refinery::PagesController#home as HTML
2014-07-01T15:41:03.962291+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered public/404.html (3.2ms)
2014-07-01T15:41:03.962657+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 78.6ms (Views: 25.1ms | ActiveRecord: 35.9ms)
2014-07-01T15:42:05.787256+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by kotinoka2014@rambler.ru
2014-07-01T15:42:12.436620+00:00 heroku[run.8038]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-01T15:42:12.500001+00:00 heroku[run.8038]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-07-01T15:42:12.461508+00:00 heroku[run.8038]: Awaiting client
2014-07-01T15:42:20.586776+00:00 heroku[run.8038]: Process exited with status 0
2014-07-01T15:42:54.780323+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stormy-caverns-7064.herokuapp.com request_id=cb66dda9-b90b-4c8d-a7f8-140ea03e9f2e fwd="94.255.67.165" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=404 bytes=1072
2014-07-01T15:42:54.778700+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 4.9ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
2014-07-01T15:42:54.773694+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"locale"=>:en}
2014-07-01T15:42:54.778610+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected
2014-07-01T15:42:54.778513+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered public/404.html (0.0ms)
2014-07-01T15:42:54.773625+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Refinery::PagesController#home as HTML
2014-07-01T15:42:54.770651+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 94.255.67.165 at 2014-07-01 15:42:54 +0000
2014-07-01T15:42:20.603887+00:00 heroku[run.8038]: State changed from up to complete
mark@mark-Aspire-5750G:~/mirprirodi$ heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Uploading SSH public key /home/mark/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done
mark@mark-Aspire-5750G:~/mirprirodi$ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Everything up-to-date
mark@mark-Aspire-5750G:~/mirprirodi$ heroku open
Opening stormy-caverns-7064... done
mark@mark-Aspire-5750G:~/mirprirodi$ heroku logs
2014-07-01T15:37:06.553873+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 94.255.67.165 at 2014-07-01 15:37:06 +0000
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569964+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569966+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569972+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"refinery_pages"'::regclass
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569975+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569980+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1163:in `exec_no_cache'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569985+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2014-07-01T15:40:02.721866+00:00 heroku[run.2189]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570007+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570014+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:229:in `yield'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570018+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:131:in `locking_enabled?'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570020+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/relation.rb:170:in `exec_queries'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570023+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activer
ecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/explain.rb:41:in `logging_query_plan'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570033+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570101+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570251+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570280+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570099+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570134+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570153+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570171+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570186+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570248+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570258+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570264+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570268+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570272+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570276+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570284+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-01T15:37:06.569982+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:660:in `block in exec_query'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570029+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/refinerycms-pages-2.1.2/app/controllers/refinery/pages_controller.rb:74:in `find_page'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570032+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570046+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570138+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570141+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570155+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570162+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570163+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570164+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:37:06.570166+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.18/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
2014-07-01T15:40:09.971485+00:00 heroku[run.2189]: State changed from up to complete
2014-07-01T15:40:02.600202+00:00 heroku[run.2189]: Awaiting client
2014-07-01T15:40:02.636111+00:00 heroku[run.2189]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-07-01T15:40
:09.961721+00:00 heroku[run.2189]: Process exited with status 0
2014-07-01T15:39:21.778866+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stormy-caverns-7064.herokuapp.com request_id=daa97508-63b7-4b44-ac56-f8e32fb9b38b fwd="94.255.67.165" dyno=web.1 connect=11ms service=18ms status=500 bytes=939
2014-07-01T15:38:20.220947+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 94.255.67.165 at 2014-07-01 15:38:20 +0000
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249464+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249469+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "refinery_pages" does not exist
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249471+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"refinery_pages"'::regclass
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249473+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249474+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249476+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249478+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249479+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249481+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"refinery_pages"'::regclass
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249482+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnu
m > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249484+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249485+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249487+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1163:in `async_exec'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249489+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1163:in `exec_no_cache'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249491+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:660:in `block in exec_query'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249493+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249495+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249496+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249497+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:659:in `exec_query'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249499+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1292:in `column_definitions'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249500+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:855:in `columns'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249501+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `block in initialize'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249503+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:229:in `yield'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249504+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:229:in `columns'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249506+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:238:in `columns_hash'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249507+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:131:in `locking_enabled?'
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249509+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/relation.rb:170:in `exec_queries'
2014-07-01T15:41:03.969437+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stormy-caverns-7064.herokuapp.com request_id=fd7f63e3-a163-46a9-ba8d-95b13ea94732 fwd="94.255.67.165" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=101ms status=404 bytes=1072
2014-07-01T15:41:03.880489+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 94.255.67.165 at 2014-07-01 15:41:03 +0000
2014-07-01T15:41:03.962488+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected
2014-07-01T15:41:03.884002+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"locale"=>:en}
2014-07-01T15:41:03.883975+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Refinery::PagesController#home as HTML
2014-07-01T15:41:03.962291+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered public/404.html (3.2ms)
2014-07-01T15:41:03.962657+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 78.6ms (Views: 25.1ms | ActiveRecord: 35.9ms)
2014-07-01T15:42:05.787256+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by kotinoka2014@rambler.ru
2014-07-01T15:42:12.436620+00:00 heroku[run.8038]: State changed from starting to up
2014-07-01T15:42:12.500001+00:00 heroku[run.8038]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-07-01T15:42:12.461508+00:00 heroku[run.8038]: Awaiting client
2014-07-01T15:42:20.586776+00:00 heroku[run.8038]: Process exited with status 0
2014-07-01T15:42:54.780323+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stormy-caverns-7064.herokuapp.com request_id=cb66dda9-b90b-4c8d-a7f8-140ea03e9f2e fwd="94.255.67.165" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=404 bytes=1072
2014-07-01T15:42:54.778700+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 4.9ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
2014-07-01T15:42:54.773694+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"locale"=>:en}
2014-07-01T15:42:54.778610+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected
2014-07-01T15:42:54.778513+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered public/404.html (0.0ms)
2014-07-01T15:42:54.773625+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Refinery::PagesController#home as HTML
2014-07-01T15:42:54.770651+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 94.255.67.165 at 2014-07-01 15:42:54 +0000
2014-07-01T15:42:20.603887+00:00 heroku[run.8038]: State changed from up to complete
2014-07-01T15:45:16.153299+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 94.255.67.165 at 2014-07-01 15:45:16 +0000
2014-07-01T15:45:16.155719+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Refinery::PagesController#home as HTML
2014-07-01T15:45:16.162021+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stormy-caverns-7064.herokuapp.com request_id=4a1ca6f5-dddc-47ac-8ca6-209f9da281f6 fwd="94.255.67.165" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=404 bytes=1072
2014-07-01T15:45:16.160881+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered public/404.html (0.0ms)
2014-07-01T15:45:16.155726+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"locale"=>:en}
2014-07-01T15:45:16.161144+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 404 Not Found in 5.3ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
2014-07-01T15:45:16.160969+00:00 app[web.1]: Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've forgotten to run `rake db:migrate`

```
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249469+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "refinery_pages" does not exist
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249471+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"refinery_pages"'::regclass
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249473+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249474+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249476+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249478+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249479+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249481+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"refinery_pages"'::regclass
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249482+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnu
m > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249484+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2014-07-01T15:38:20.249485+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
```

Comment: It is didn't help me!